# Batch data flow task edit in SQL Server Data Tools (SSIS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, dataflowtask

I have a database with several thousand tables. Now I need to import some of that tables to another database (names and columns are identical).
I have created SSIS package and with "SSIS Import and Export Wizard" created about 300 data flow tasks to import table data (5 tables in each data flow task). But many of them contains error: Failure inserting into the readonly column "timestamp". So, I need to remove these columns from all sources and destinations. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: How many is some? 1? 10? 100?

Comment: unmap column 'timestamp'?

Comment: I need to import about 1500 tables. I think, about 1000 of them has timestamp columns. It's very difficult to unmap them all by hands.